# how to store arrays into a database

Tags: database, array

I'm trying the store multiple rows into a database. The number of fields will change. Below is the way that I use to store just one row.

```
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['save'])){
      $wpdb->insert('wp_table_name',
          array(
              'field_a' => $_POST['field_a'],
              'field_b' => $_POST['field_b'],
              'field_c' => $_POST['field_c'],
              'field_d' => $_POST['field_d']             
              ),
          array(
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s'
              )
          );
  }
  ?>

  <form>
      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <input type="text" name="field_a[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_b[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_c[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="field_d[]"/>

      <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

What WP does for arrays (and objects) on some contexts (such as post fields) is using [`maybe_serialize()`](http://queryposts.com/function/maybe_serialize/)/[`maybe_unserialize()`](http://queryposts.com/function/maybe_unserialize/) to turn such types (and just them) to and from serialized (string-typed) representation.

While this simplifies workflow it comes with penalties, such as being unable to properly query through such data and common issues with migration (seriazlization-unaware tools or actions easily ruin serialized strings).

If you have control over design of custom table and it serves specific dedicated function — you should probably design it in a way that you don't store whole arrays in first place.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with my question?

Comment: @user759235 ...it explains how WordPress stores arrays into database when needed? :)

Comment: good explanation. Or maybe we can create our own migration tool. But the problem with querying filter for data still intact.

Comment: Great answer btw. What if we're storing arrays of data associated with a specific native object? i.e. a list of favorite foods per user, or a list of URLs associated with a particular post

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
      $wpdb->insert('wp_table_name',
          array(
              'field_a' => maybe_serialize( $_POST['field_a'] ),
              'field_b' => maybe_serialize( $_POST['field_b'] ),
              'field_c' => maybe_serialize( $_POST['field_c'] ),
              'field_d' => maybe_serialize( $_POST['field_d'] )             
              ),
          array(
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s',
              '%s'
              )
          );
}
?>
```

Use the maybe_unserialize function to get the value as array.

Comment: Doesn't this saves everything in 1 row? I need to store every value in seperate rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can save post meta with the same meta key, just set the `$unique` parameter to false.

```php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    foreach ($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){
        if ( 'save' === $post_key )
            continue;
        if ( is_array($post_value) ) {
            foreach ( $post_value as $key => value ) {
                add_post_meta($post_id, $post_key . '[' . $key . ']', $post_value, false);
            }
        }
        else{
            add_post_meta($post_id, $post_key, $post_value, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you can call `get_post_meta ( $post_id, $post_key, false )` to retrieve all of the meta values with that particular meta key.

That of course if this was a post, and you want to save something related to that post. For example if your post was the form and you want to sve the submissions as meta-data for that specific form(post).

else i would just do 1 insert to the table per field on a foreach like the example I gave above but using the `$wpdb->insert()` method you used.